# How to debug with remote binaries radare2?

Tags: radare2, remote

i am reading differents documentation about radare2 but i don't read nothing about how can i debug a binary in remote machine.

Actually i am a security research and i need execute binaries in other laboratory virtual machine (winxp).

Thanks for all.

Comment: https://radare.gitbooks.io/radare2book/content/remoting_capabilities.html will probably help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This blogpost](http://radare.today/posts/using-radare2/) will probably answer your question. Search for windbg, if you're only interested in this part. Maybe using the r2 debugger on the target works with rap://.